# How do I determine a Java method return type from parameters?

Tags: java, methods, parameters, header

I need an explanation. When no method header is given, how would I know what return type the method would give from context clues?

for example:

```
int someNum = someWord.someMethod();
```

I'm a beginner, sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: You have to have access to the entire method declaration, including the return type. You cannot infer the return type from parameter types.  From where are you getting a method declaration without a return type?  Can you show what you got and where you got it from?

Comment: I have to wonder if this question is an XY Problem in disguise. What's the overall problem that you're trying to solve, as they very likely is a better way to go about solving it?

Comment: In your code above, you can only guess that someMethod returns int, since that's the type of variable that you're assigning it to ... .unless that assignment is wrong.

Comment: if you feed an unknown animal, you just won't know what comes out on the other end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking about `someMethod()` the the return value is assigned to an `int` variable, so the return type is `int`. The method signature will look like this

```
public int someMethod() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type is not necessarily `int`, it is any type that is assignment compatible with `int`.

In addition to `int`, it could also be `Integer`, `byte`, `Byte`, `short`, `Short`, `char`, or `Character`.